# Changing tikz-timing's font

Tags: fonts, tikz-timing

I'm trying to change the font `tikz-timing` is using inside its traces. In the following MWE, i'd like to have the `aaa` written in `\rmfamily`: `tikz-timing`'s manual suggests that there is a key named `timing/font`, but I have no idea how to use it; all combinations I've tried so far did not change anything, and I'm way past the "educated" part in my guessing here...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
test & [timing/.style={font=\rmfamily}] 2D{aaa} \\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the correct key (thanks Ulrike for giving me the crucial hint of searching for hardcoded `\sffamily`s in `tikz-timing.sty`): it's `timing/d/text/.append style={font=\rmfamily}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/d/text/.append style={font=\rmfamily}] 
test & 2D{aaa} \\    \end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

tikz-timing has burried some `\sffamily` commands quite deep in some styles. In your case the "D" calls a style that sets the sans serif, so if you want to change it locally you will have to set it inside the argument of D:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
test &2D{[font=\rmfamily]aaa} \\    \end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```